# NPM Error when installing packages of a new project

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-install

I ran to this error when I tried to install packages from a project.
Yesterday I tried and worked perfectly, but today I face this issue. I tried to install packages from another project and it works fine. I really don't understand if the problem is in my version of npm or something, but I am almost sure that I didn't change anything from yesterday to today.

Any idea of what it's related?
Thanks in advance!

```
➜  backend git:(main) ✗ npm install
npm WARN deprecated natives@1.1.6: This module relies on Node.js's internals and will break at some point. Do not use it, and update to graceful-fs@4.x.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/ref.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/argon2.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/core.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/thread.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/libargon2/argon2/src/encoding.o
npm ERR!   LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/argon2.a
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/argon2/src/argon2_node.o
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/bin/node /Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node --module_name=argon2 --module_path=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.2.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/releases/download/v0.27.2/argon2-v0.27.2-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/releases/download/v0.27.2/argon2-v0.27.2-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for argon2@0.27.2 and node@16.2.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/releases/download/v0.27.2/argon2-v0.27.2-napi-v3-darwin-arm64-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.2.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.2.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/alansanchez/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.2.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/alansanchez/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.2.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/alansanchez/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.2.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.2.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! clang: error: no such file or directory: 'Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/node-addon-api'
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/argon2/src/argon2_node.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node" "--module_name=argon2" "--module_path=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/bin/node /Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3/argon2.node --module_name=argon2 --module_path=/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2/lib/binding/napi-v3 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/alansanchez/.nvm/versions/node/v16.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.2.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.npm/_logs/2022-01-18T09_06_02_542Z-debug.log
```

EDIT:
Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^3.2.1",
    "@sentry/node": "^6.2.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.2.2",
    "argon2": "^0.27.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.918.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "dotnet": "^1.1.4",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.6",
    "iban": "0.0.14",
    "ibantools": "^3.3.0",
    "ioredis": "^4.24.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lit-html": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.23",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "objects-to-csv": "^1.3.6",
    "openpgp": "^5.0.1",
    "prisma-offset-pagination": "^0.0.4",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "query-string": "^7.0.0",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.2.0",
    "stringify-object": "^4.0.0",
    "stripe": "^8.145.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prisma": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: First of, delete `node_nodules` and try again. If that does not help share the `package.json`, it seems that a module is deprecated and has to be updated.

Comment: The node_modules folder was not created. I cloned the project and tried to install the packages as a start but did not work.
The packages are:

Comment: Please do not put code into comments, it looks very messy. You can update your question and delete the comments.

Comment: Sorry, first time using the platform. Thanks for the comment!. I already edit the question :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `argon2` package makes problems due to security reasons. If you remove it, the installation works just fine.

Can you try running following commands? :

```
 npm remove argon2
 npm install argon2@latest
```

after updating the package you should be able to run normally `npm install`.

If that does not do the trick, I suggest to either open up an issue on the `argon2`  [github repository](https://github.com/ranisalt/node-argon2/issues) OR to use some other hashing module, depending on your needs.

#### Error message

If you look closely into the error message you can see the following path indicating the problem:

`npm ERR! path /Users/alansanchez/Desktop/SXC Files/stylexchange-web-app/backend/node_modules/argon2`

It points on `argon2` so you have a hint what's the problem

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!. I can't believe that the problem was just the space in the name of the folder in the path! :(. I spent like 3hs trying to figure this out!. You are a lifesaver, Silvan! Thanks again!